# Checking to see if any parameters exist within function call in Pylons

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid, mako

How can I find out the number of parameters (if any at all) that were passed in.

I'm using Mako and I'm calling the template function with:

```
${article_util.small_article_popular(c.footer_popular_articles[0])}
```

Within the template:

```
<%def name="small_article_popular(article)">

// check to see if any parameters were passed in

</%def>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `small_article_popular(article)` is effectively a Python function, so it cannot be called with no parameters, as per the signature. If you want to check if `article` is `None`, then just do that.. `if article:`.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up adding an additional argument to the function call and where I didn't want to call it (when I re-use that function) I'm just adding it as (arg1, arg2 = None). Works great.